# Retrofit is stripping trailing slash in url

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, retrofit2

I have a url like such:

https://www.dummy.com/api/v1/

```
public interface DummyService {
    @POST("path/")
    Observable<Response<Void>> postToDummy(@Body String someBody);
}
```

I want to keep the `/` at the end of my url (after path), but when retrofit makes the REST request, it strips the `/`. How can I prevent this?

This is the url Retrofit is making a request to:
https://www.dummy.com/api/v1/path

Here's what I want:
https://www.dummy.com/api/v1/path/

Comment: How are you verifying that Retrofit is stripping the trailing `/` from your path? According to the documentation of `Retrofit.Builder.baseUrl()`, it should not be: https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Retrofit.Builder.html#baseUrl-okhttp3.HttpUrl-

Comment: @BenP. I am printing the request to console using the httplogginginterceptor for retrofit, and it's showing the request is missing the trailing `/`. I am also getting the same responses by verifying it on postman with and without the `/`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the slash at the end, as it doesn't change the target URL. If you're having issues with adding paths to your endpoints, you can use the @Path annotation that Retrofit provides.

Comment: It does in my case. The request fails without the trailing `/` and succeeds with it.